# Не загружаются зависимости в проекте wpf C# Visual Studio 2019 Community

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio

При загрузки проекта происходит непредвиденная ошибка:

```
Recoverable
System.InvalidOperationException: Build target stack was corrupted and contain other unfinished targets. Expect: 'DesignTimeMarkupCompilation', Actual: 'MarkupCompilePass1'.
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.ErrorListLogger.Build_TargetFinished(Object sender, TargetFinishedEventArgs e)
```

Также не загружаются никакие зависимости и не получается запустить Debug
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Зависимости проекта]

Эта ошибка появляется во всех проектах WPF.

Полная переустановка IDE не помогла.

Comment: В списке ошибок что?

Comment: Там только предупреждение 
`Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Предупреждение NU1701 Пакет "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000" был восстановлен с помощью ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8", а не целевой платформы проекта "net5.0-windows7.0". Этот пакет может быть не полностью совместим с вашим проектом. AMRMI C:\Project\WpfExample-master\WpfPaging\AMRMI.csproj 1`

Comment: И почему Вы ставите .NET Framework пакеты в .NET 5 проект? Не кажется это странным?

Comment: Проблема не в этом пакете

Comment: Как знать... Это вообще Ваш проект? Он раньше запускался на этом компьютере? `во всех проектах WPF` - я так понимаю и совершенно чистый проект, созданный с нуля у вас также не запускается? Создать и запустить без студии пробовали, через консоль?

Comment: Проект мой на основе https://github.com/BashkaMen/WpfExample, запускался без ошибок, даже полностью пустой проект не запускается, через консоль не пробовал.

Comment: Попробуйте через консоль: Создайте где-либо пустую директорию, дале в консоли `cd путь`, далее `dotnet new wpf`, как сгенерирует все, пишите `dotnet run`. Если не запустит, то у вас проблема с SDK и прочими приблудами, переустанавливайте .NET5. Если запустит, то у вас проблема в студии, как фиксить - не знаю, я бы удалил полностью, почистил все следы от нее, а затем ставил бы свежую.

Comment: Проект запустило, а VS я через soft organizer отслеживал потом со всеми следами удалял, походу винду переставлять, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогли эти команды.

```
1. dism /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
2. sfc /scannow
```

Их нужно прописать в cmd